# What the findcontour() theory in opencv?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, contour

I use `findcontours()` in emgu, but I want to know what is the theory. I know `findcontours()`'s parameter and how to use. So is the 
algorithm `convexhull`? Or where can I find the related knowledge?

Comment: I found wrong Keyword, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm used for FindContours() is `Suzuki85 algorithm`

You can read more on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suzuki-Kasami_algorithm) or [OpenCV Guide](http://opencv.itseez.com/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours)